# python variable name use

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was wondering if it was Pythonic to reuse repeatedly the same variable name in a function if you are making modification to its content instead of using a temporary name.

example:

```
NAMES = ['abc def', 'ghi jkl', 'ghi jkl']

def clean_names(names):
    names = [name.title() for name in names] # Put upper case for first letters
    names = list(set(names)) # Remove duplicates
    return names
```

Output:

```
['Ghi Jkl', 'Abc Def']
```

My feeling is if it's make the code easier to follow then why not!

Comment: You want to avoid shadowing. i.e. using `NAMES` inside `clean_names`. Unless it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: What's the point of the `names` parameter if you use `NAMES` in the list comprehension?

Comment: You can name a variable (almost) anything you want and can reuse and change the values willy-nilly. As noted by @Barmar watch the parameter use.

Comment: @roganjosh The question isn't about how the function is called, it's just about whether it's good style to reassign the variable `names` on the second line of the function.

Comment: @Skam my mistake, i meant to refer to the parameter not the NAMES list, i fixed the code

Answer (score 1):

It's not non-pythonic to re-use the variable names if you are altering the data set, however, in your case you could just remove the 2nd line where you reassign the variable and just use a return statement

```
NAMES = ['abc def', 'ghi jkl', 'ghi jkl']

def clean_names(list_of_names):
    names = [name.title() for name in list_of_names]
    return list(set(names)) # Return a list without duplicates
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's what gets passed to the method `clean_names()`, but in this case he has used dummy data ('abc def' will not contain a `.title()`)

Comment: Hopefully he comes back to clear this up for us

Comment: you are right off course. My question was about style. I frequently use the same name for multiple alteration to a data set given to a function to make the code more readable: one line per alteration. Thanks